# Spring MVC, @RequestParam initialize default list with one empty string

Tags: spring-mvc

Is there a way to initialize a default list with one empty string using the `@RequestParam` annotation in Spring MVC?

If I use the following code, the list is empty:

```
public String example(
        @RequestParam(value = "example", defaultValue = "")
                List<String> exampleList) {
    return "";
}
```

Using `defaultValue = ","` instead, results in a list with two empty strings. My current solution is to check if the list is empty and if so add the empty string to it but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `defaultValue = ","` use `defaultValue = " "`. It's work and your list is initialise with one empty string.